# Android Task is not Completing using Places API

Tags: android, android-asynctask, task, google-places-api

I am trying to basically copy the code from the Places API docs, [found here,](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place) however, while the code seems to work, the task never returns successful or complete and not executing that code block. This is my code, but it is mostly the same as the Google docs with some changes.

```
public void refreshLocation(TextView textView, PlacesClient placesClient) {
        // Use fields to define the data types to return.
        textView.setText("Loading...");
        List<Place.Field> placeFields = Collections.singletonList(Place.Field.NAME);

        // Use the builder to create a FindCurrentPlaceRequest.
        FindCurrentPlaceRequest request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields);
        textView.setText("Starting task . . .");
        Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> placeResponse = placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request);
        textView.setText("Task set . . .");

        placeResponse.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Double likelihood = 0.0;
                String name = "";
                FindCurrentPlaceResponse response = task.getResult();
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : response.getPlaceLikelihoods()) {
                    textView.setText("Task successful");
                    if (placeLikelihood.getLikelihood() > likelihood) {
                        likelihood = placeLikelihood.getLikelihood();
                        name = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName();
                    }
                }
                if (likelihood != 0.0) {
                    likelihood = likelihood * 100;
                    textView.setText(String.format("You are at {}. \n {}% accurate", name, likelihood));
                } else {
                    textView.setText("Error: No Location Found.");
                }
            } else {
                Exception exception = task.getException();
                if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Am I missing something in regards to starting the task? Is there some way to kick it off or execute it? Is this something that would be solved with AsyncTask, even though the Google Docs don't use it?

Comment: Same here. Using the Autocomplete also doesn't seem to return anything.